# Why use get_context_data (self,**kwargs) and super ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset

In a class-based view, I simply use `get_context_data` as a function but why

```
class CBV (TemplateView):

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super ().get_context_data  (**kwargs)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "but why"? First of all, you should `return` that context, and in case you do not want to add/change anything, you can simply remove this `get_context_data` function.

Comment: Here i don't understand  the purpose of using get_context_data function and why super() is called

Comment: To add extra elements to the template. The `super()` call is used, since there are a lot of subclasses that patch the `get_context_data` already (adding forms, etc.) so we want to take this into account as well.

Comment: Should media static needs get_context_data

Comment: Media static is not a class-based view, it is a function attached to the `ContextMixin`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind information. I am beginner at djangi web development. Can you help me from where i can learn django project web development

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like the [documentation on **`get_context_data`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) says:

> Returns a dictionary representing the **template context**. The keyword arguments provided will make up the returned context. (..)

If you thus let the function return a dictionary `{'foo': 42}`, then in your template you can write a variable `{{ foo }}`, and then it will be replaced with `42`.

This is frequently used to pass all kinds of data to a template: the user that is logged in, forms, querysets, etc. The template can then render these components accordingly.

A typical use case is:

> ```
> def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
>     context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
>     context['number'] = random.randrange(1, 100)
>     return context
> ```

Where thus here the "child class" adds an extra element `number` to the context.

Here we thus make a call to next function in the *method resolution order (MRO)*. This is typically the parent of a class, although the rules of the MRO are a bit more complex in the case of *multiple inheritance*. The reason is that these parents can add data to the context as well. So by calling the `get_context_data` of the parent, the parent returns a dictionary that might contain some data already, and then the child(ren) can each in turn add more data to the `context` (or change it), in reverse *MRO* order. This however only will happen if *every* child performs a `super().get_context_data(**kwargs)` call, and patches the result (and thus not construct a new dictionary).

Comment: Thanks  willem van onsem

Comment: What baffles me is surely calling get_context_data from within get_context_data would start a recursive loop?

Comment: @RossSymonds: it is the `get_context_data()` of the `super()`, this is a proxy-object that will walk up the MRO for the first ancestor.

Comment: can we get data from multiple models' to the context using this function?
like `from .models import Categories, Comments, Price`
so from there, I want to pass data to my template.
Thanks :)

Comment: @uyivzola: yes, you can add these all to the context with `context['categories'] = Categories.objects.all()` and so on to pass these to the template.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and the only use case I see for accepting **kwargs in get_context_data is to lower the priority of your context variable. This ensures that it will be overridden by any other mixin or parent class if present. Otherwise, providing a resulting dictionary update will have a different effect due to the MRO position of this mixin.

```py
class LowPrioContextMixIn:
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     return super().get_context_data(low_prio_var=True, **kwargs)
```