# Django: what are the **kwargs arguments in get_context_data(self, **kwargs)?

Tags: python, django, django-views

What are the `**kwargs` arguments in `get_context_data(self, **kwargs)`? For example, in `SomeListView.as_view()`, what gets passed as `**kwargs` in the `get_context_data` method?

Comment: I thought I edited my answer in the other post you did around 10 hours ago. Doesn't that help? Btw if you still have problems pls comment there

Comment: You might want to take a look at how a view, like a `ListView` is implemented: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.list/ListView/ This site performs MRO resolution, and thus shows the "code flow". But based on your question, the problem is likely not Django, but more Python's object model.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631651/why-use-get-context-data-self-kwargs-and-super/75613745#75613745