# understand a view script in Django

Tags: python, django

hi guys i'm starting to see django in particular how the views are structured. I have some unresolved doubts as an amateur. .

Here, for example, I have a view that should show all the products in the database on a page.

```
class HomeView(EcomMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        all_products = Product.objects.all().order_by("-id")
        paginator = Paginator(all_products, 8)
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
        print(page_number)
        product_list = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        context['product_list'] = product_list
        return context
```

"`get_context`" returns a dictionary representing the context of the model, but I don't understand what "self and kwargs" would be.

Then extra elements are added to the model with the call "`super().Get_context_data(** kwargs)`."

Then all the products present are taken and ordered "`all_products = Product.objects.all(). Order_by("-id")` ".

Here I don't understand that "`order_by("-id")"` . In the" Product "table there is no field named id.

Paginator comes with a list of objects as well as the number of elements you want to have on each page.

Then the page number is requested with the get method and printed. (Why is it printed?)

"`product_list = paginator.get_page(page_number)`", returns a specific product page in product_list.

I don't understand what is done in the penultimate line.

Comment: `self` is the instance of the class. You can `print(kwargs)` and see what's in there. `order_by("-id")` arranges the items in descending order. `id` is an `AutoField` see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: In the penultimate line, the dictionary `context` is being assigned a new key `product_list` whose value is `product_list` *the one with the paginator*

Comment: About ```get_context_data(self, **kwargs)``` - You can [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631651/why-use-get-context-data-self-kwargs-and-super) this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I will try to explain some things to you and where to start your study:

1. **self** - this is the standard name of the first argument for object methods.
2. In Python, you can pass a variable number of arguments in two ways: ***args** for unnamed arguments; ****kwargs** for named arguments. We use *args and **kwargs as arguments when we don't know in advance how many values we want to pass to the function.
3. By default, results returned by a QuerySet are ordered by the ordering tuple given by the ordering option in the model’s Meta. You can override this on a per-QuerySet basis by using the **order_by** method. In your case, this is sorting by ID.
4. The identifier **id** is added automatically.
5. Read about pagination here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/

Comment: ok, i'm starting to understand ...but why is the page number printed?  one last question ... the arguments that are passed to HomeView are TemplateView which serves to the base class and make it become a template ... while EcoMixin what is it for?

Comment: 1. EcoMixin - this is an argument that needs to be imported from somewhere. It seems to me that you took some code example and are trying to parse it. You should start with simple things and refer to the django documentation first. Everything is disassembled there to the smallest detail. 2. print(page_number) this example does not carry any semantic meaning if you think that this line is factorial in this code.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ django documentation. It will help you understand both the basics and complex things.